# App published registration with phone number fail

Tags: google-play, release

My app works fine on release mode and debug mode, I even send a published apk file to a friend to install and works fine too. But today when I finally released my app on play store I discovered that registration with phone number doesn't work anymore,  more exactly my app doesn't send verification code now.

Comment: I mention that my rules on firebase database are read, write == true. So there's no need to be logged In. Could this be the reason why my app on play store don't send verification code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem was not about Firebase Database Rules.
The problem was that I provided SHA-1 signing code generated by Android Studio in Firebase Project Settings. 
The fix was about providing SHA-1 signing code from Google Play Console to Firebase Project Settings. Hope this helps somebody!